# Should I use index on frequently updated table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I have a table where we will inserting 1000 records per minute and updating the same records to change the status in the next minute on the basis of 2 columns.I am planning to create separate index on the 2 columns. Is it advisable to create one index on both the columns or separate index on 2 columns. We will be selecting on both the columns frequently.

Answer (score 4):

If you are writing queries of the form

```
SELECT <<something>>
  FROM table_name
 WHERE column_1 = <<x>>
   AND column_2 = <<y>>
```

in an OLTP system, you'd almost certainly want a single composite index on `column_1, column_2`.  OLTP type queries are generally unable to use multiple b-tree indexes on a single table in a single query.  Doing so would require doing a (relatively inefficient) b-tree to bitmap conversion which is not something the optimizer would frequently choose.

Comment: This specific table updates frequently (every minute). Is it okay to have indexes on these kind of tables?

Comment: @user3557442 - If the updates are using predicates on `column_1` and `column_2` to find the row(s) to update, you'd really want the composite index to make finding the row(s) to update efficient.